# Can we find an operator that satisfies this equation?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

$f^{\alpha }\left( \overrightarrow {0}\right) +f^{\beta }\left( \overrightarrow {0}\right) =f^{\alpha \beta +\alpha +\beta }\left( \overrightarrow {0}\right)$

Is there a function $f$ from $R^{\infty}$ to $R^{\infty}$ that satisfies this equation for all natural ${\alpha}$ and ${\beta}$ ?

I already know that any function that has $f\left( \overrightarrow {0}\right)= \overrightarrow {0}$ satisfies the equation, so are there any other functions that satisfy the equation?

Thank you in advance!

*My phrasing for this being a "functional equation" was flawed. All I really wanted to know was the existance of a function that satisfies the equation above.

*The superscripts indicate iterates of $f$.

Comment: I don't see any "functional equation" here. Are you asking whether there exists a sequence g(n) satisfying g(mn+m+n)=g(m)+g(n) for all natural m,n?

Comment: Are your superscripts indexing into infinite vectors, or indicating iterates of $f$?  If the former, then, as @AlexandreEremenko points out, you aren't really looking at *functions*, just individual *elements*, of $\mathbb R^\infty$; and then you can just put $g(0) = 0$, assign $g(p - 1)$ arbitrarily for $p$ prime, and put $g(n - 1) = \prod_{p \mid n} g(p - 1)$ (the product over all primes dividing $n$, counted with multiplicity).

Comment: My m and n are your $\alpha$ and $\beta$. My $g(n)$ is your $f^\alpha(0)$.